# Any way to access Notes in Gmail? [JavaScript / Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I'm writing an open source app that helps users visualize notes and short snippets of text as a graph to see how they're all connected.

I already connected it to Evernote and Twitter and now want to also make it possible to import the notes from the Notes folder in Gmail. However, I can't find any APIs for that.

Anybody knows how to import Notes from Gmail?

Maybe there's a Node.js module that has this functionality (I looked but did not find).

Comment: Which notes folder? I don't have one.

Comment: I have one. And actually I found this module https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap using which you just access the gmail account and retrieve any folder you need.

Comment: Then it's just an IMAP folder that you created.